# Yii2, Codeception: Setting unknown property: yii\web\Application::class

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

When I run Codeception, e.g.:

```
codecept run
```

I receive the following error message:

> [yii\base\UnknownPropertyException]
>     Setting unknown property: yii\web\Application::class

If I open the test version of the application main page

```
https://localhost/yii/frontend/web/index-test.php/
```

then I receive this message:

> Exception (Unknown Property) 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with
>   message 'Setting unknown property: yii\web\Application::class'
>
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:[197](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Component.php#L197)
>
> Stack trace:
>   0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php([521](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/BaseYii.php#L521)): yii\base\Component->__set('class', 'yii\db\Connecti...')
>
> 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php([105](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Object.php#L105)): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\web\Application), Array)
>
> 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php([206](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Application.php#L206)): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
>
> 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\ap1_epas\web\index-test.php(18): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
>
> 4 {main}

In the file index-test.php is on the line 18 the following code:

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

I use Selenium. Two weeks ago had the tests worked. I have made no changes in Codeception or configuration since then.

Comment: What version of Yii framework are you using?

Comment: I use Yii2 (2.0.8).

Comment: Does the error also occur when opening index.php? If not, what´s the difference to index-test.php? I guess there is some mistake in yii config params.

Comment: The application (index.php) works perfectly. The error is occuring only by tests. The configuration of tests was not changed since a few months ago. I have controlled all configuration files, but I have found nothing suspicious. My problem is, that I don't know, what should I look for.

Comment: If the error occurs when opening https://localhost/yii/frontend/web/index-test.php/ it will have nothing to do with codeception.

Comment: Please post index-test.php, tests/codeception/config/acceptance.php and all config-files that are different / not used by the working index.php

Comment: The errorlog reports an error at component.php so I guess your config will be wrong in the components-section. Check for "class"!

Comment: Thanks! I have found that one of the config files in "/../../tests/codeception/config/ap1_epas/acceptance.php" was redundant. So I commented the line: "require(YII_APP_BASE_PATH . '/frontend/config/params-local.php')" and everything works.